# iOS: Pointer get lost when poping back to parentView

Tags: pointers, ios6, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I code for iOS 6.1 with ARC and have a problem that my objects in the nsmutablearray get "lost".
I will explain it in more detail:

1. There is a parent view which has a NSMutableArray which should hold some objects(addresses)
2. Everytime I hit the button the data of the Array will be displayed with NSLog and then the navigation controller pushes to the ChildView
3. The childview generates a new address object

If I do this and then press the back button in the view and wants to try the same case (again pressing the button) the data in the array is lost and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

My assumption: When I go back to parentView ARC deallocates the second view and everything in it. But my Address object will be referenced from the array so that the ARC counter for this object should not be 0.

Can anyone help me?
Here is the concrete code

ParentViews Controller h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *adresses;
@property int count;
-(void)goFurther;
@end
```

ParentViews Controller m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "Address.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title=@"First View";
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add address" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self action:@selector(goFurther)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    self.adresses=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.count=0;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void) goFurther{
    for (Address *a in self.adresses) {
        NSLog(@"Adresse:");
        NSLog(a.street);
        NSLog(a.door);
    }
    self.count++;
    SecondViewController *second=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithView:self];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:true];
}

@end
```

ChildViews Controller h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property ViewController * viewCon;
-(id) initWithView: (ViewController*) view;
@end
```

ChildViews Controller m:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "Address.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithView: (ViewController*) view{
    self = [super init];
    self.viewCon=view;
    Address *a=[Address alloc];
    a.street=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Street %d", self.viewCon.count];
    a.door=@"Door";
    [self.viewCon.adresses addObject: a];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title=@"Second View";
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your data back to the parent view before dismissing the child view.

Declare a @protocol (say, called `ChildControllerDelegate`) in your child controller's `.h` file with a method `didDismissWithData:` with some data type that is suitable for you (maybe string or dictionary). Have the parent view controller conform to the protocol. Create a @property of the child called `delegate` of type `id<ChildControllerDelegate>`

Then before dismissing the child, call

```
[self.delegate didDismissWithData:newData];
```

In the parent controller, handle this message and save your new address.

Comment: I tried it and made a delegate object in childs controller and the protocol like yours and added the protocol in the parent view...the method in parent looks like this:
-(void)addAddress:(Address*)address{
    NSLog(@"Try to add address");
    NSLog(address.street);
    [self.adresses addObject:address];
}
This works fine as long as my child view is not dealocated. But when the child view is deleated the address object (pointer saved in the array) is not accessible anymore

Comment: The problem is that when I try to access the object in the parent (after passing it back with a delegate and after the childViewController had been dealocated) the object is deleted and I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Did I declare the object incorrect or so?

Comment: This is basic stuff. When you push/segue/update your child view you have to configure it with the selected object.